# PHP check if value exists

Tags: php, mysql

I’m trying to write a `if` code, but can't figure out how.

In my database table i have the primary key `id`.
In the table i have `objekt_nr` & `element_nr`.
Now, before i call an `INSTERT` i need to check if `objekt_nr` with `element_nr` already exist.
`If` `objekt_nr` With `element_nr` exist. Then `UPDATE` instead of `INSTERT`. Only id can be unique.

example of table:

id......objekt_nr......element_nr

1.......1...............1

2.......1...............2

3.......1...............3

4.......2...............1

5.......2...............2

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
echo '<a href=".php">Fortsätt...</a><br />';
echo $path=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

//Load file into PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

//Loop threw file to get data
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = 'J'; //$worksheet->getHighestColumn(''); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

//Echo file info
echo "<br>The worksheet ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
echo ' and ' . $highestRow . ' row.';
echo '<br>Data: <table border="1"><tr>';

//Loop threw colum, rows and cells
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
        //$dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
        echo '<td>' . $val . '<br></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
$val=array();
for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
$cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
$val[] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
}
// Prepare Query 
    $query = "INSERT INTO phpexcel(
                objekt_nr,
                objekt_rev,
                element_nr,
                element_hojd,
                element_typ,
                element_langd,
                element_oppningar,
                element_vikt,
                element_ritare,
                element_status) 
            VALUES ( 
            :objekt_nr, 
            :objekt_rev, 
            :element_nr,
            :element_hojd,
            :element_typ,
            :element_langd,
            :element_oppningar,
            :element_vikt,
            :element_ritare,
            :element_status
        )"; 

    // Security measures
    $query_params = array(  
        ':objekt_nr' => $val[0],
        ':objekt_rev' => $val[1],
        ':element_nr' => $val[2],
        ':element_hojd' => $val[3],
        ':element_typ' => $val[4],
        ':element_langd' => $val[5],
        ':element_oppningar' => $val[6],
        ':element_vikt' => $val[7],
        ':element_ritare' => $val[8],
        ':element_status' => $val[9]
    ); 
    try {  
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 


//echo $query."\n";
}
}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ? Assuming `objeckt_nr` is the key. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ definitely the easiest solution, but it's worth pointing out that it is a MySQL extension (non-standard sql)

Comment: @TimSeguine this is possible with MySQL - I'm unsure what you're saying.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑI am saying that it is *only* possible with MySQL. Depending on what the OP needs, this lack of portability to other implementations may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: @TimSeguine I understand. However, OP has tagged `mysql` and not mentioned the answer should have portability in mind. Nevertheless, a good point.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑI know, I am just saying it is worth mentioning. It is always good to know if you are relying on features that are not portable.

Comment: @hd I did update my question a bit. I have to check two fields, to see if there is an UPDATE required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options here.

1) Make "objekt_nr" field a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key and use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html). This is pretty much @hd 's answer in the comments.

2) Check for an existing "objekt_nr" and "element_nr" and run the appropriate query

```
$check_duplicate_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM phpexcel WHERE objekt_nr = ':objekt_nr' AND element_nr = ':element_nr'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($check_duplicate_query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if($rows[0] > 0) {
    //UPDATE
} else {
    //INSERT
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
```

EDIT:

Just thought of a 3rd option

Create another field "objekt_element_nr" and set this field to unique.
This field gets assigned objekt and element number combination, which from your example should be unique.

e.g. 1_1, 1_2, 1_3, 2_1, 2_2, etc.

Then simply use the `REPLACE` function I linked to above.

Your `$query_params` would look like

```
$query_params = array(  
        ':objekt_nr' => $val[0],
        ':objekt_rev' => $val[1],
        ':element_nr' => $val[2],
        ':objekt_element_nr' => $val[0].'_'.$val[2]
        ':element_hojd' => $val[3],
        ':element_typ' => $val[4],
        ':element_langd' => $val[5],
        ':element_oppningar' => $val[6],
        ':element_vikt' => $val[7],
        ':element_ritare' => $val[8],
        ':element_status' => $val[9]
    );
```

Comment: @ConnectedSystemes I Can't make `objekt_nr` unique because two `element_nr` having the same `objekt_nr`. `element_nr` can be unique. But i need to match.. if the `objekt_nr`with the `element_nr`exist, then update it.

Comment: @ConnectedSystemes Thank you! I will try this and come back! I've also updated my explaining question! (I was wrong with the unique of elemenr_nr. ONLY id can be unique!)

Comment: Added 3rd possible solution

Comment: I also recommend using @ʰᵈˑ's answer in the comment instead of the REPLACE command (dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) because REPLACE will delete then insert new row, whereas INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE will update existing row. Better performance wise.

Comment: @ConnectedSystsmes I really like your 3rd solution! I go with this, and it worked exactly how i wanted! Made my day! Thank U!

Comment: Could you accept my answer then? Let's others know you found a solution (and gives me internet points :P)